# Bundler says I already activated a gem but my gemfile requires a different version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I ran "bundle exec install" yet I still get the following error:

```
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated metaclass 0.0.2, but your Gemfile requires metaclass 0.0.1. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't it be executing in the context of the current app?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to use:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle update metaclass` from within your application directory so that the version specified in the `Gemfile` gets applied.